# Number of annotations at JUnit test incorrect

Tags: java, unit-testing, annotations, junit4

I have created some custom annotations to use for system tests which are run via JUnit.

A test e.g. looks like this:

```
@TestCaseName("Change History")
public class ChangeHistory extends SystemTestBase
{    
    @Test
    @Risk(1)
    public void test()
    {
...
```

I am now implementing a Test Runner which shall report the test name, the risk and the somewhere for documentation purposes.

```
public class MyRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner
{
    ...
    @Override
    protected void runChild(final FrameworkMethod method, RunNotifier notifier) 
    {
        ...
        System.out.println("Class annotations:");
        Annotation[] classanno = klass.getAnnotations();
        for (Annotation annotation : classanno) {
            System.out.println(annotation.annotationType());
        }

        System.out.println("Method annotations:");
        Annotation[] methanno = method.getAnnotations();
        for (Annotation annotation : methanno) {
            System.out.println(annotation.annotationType());
        }
```

The output is

```
Class annotations:
Method annotations:
interface org.junit.Test
```

So `getAnnotations()` seems to return annotations of JUnit only and not all annotations. This is not mentioned [in the documentation of JUnit](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/runners/model/FrameworkMethod.html):

> Returns the annotations on this method

The return type is `java.lang.Annotation` which made me believe that I can use any annotation. I defined the annotation like follows - I just used it and when there was an error I let Eclipse generate the annotation:

```
public @interface Risk {
    int value();
}
```

**How do I get all annotations of the test class and test method?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the retention policy of the `Risk` annotation to `RUNTIME`. Otherwise, the annotation will be discarded after the compilation and won't be available during the execution of the code.

This should be working:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Risk {
  int value();
}
```